# brute force web crawler, how to use Link Extractor towards increased automation. Scrapy

Tags: python, xpath, hyperlink, web-crawler, scrapy

I'm using a scrapy web crawler to extract a bunch of data, as I describe [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28448840/define-a-specific-web-crawling-rule-with-scrapy-how-to-structure), I've figured out a brute force way to get the information I want, but.. it's really pretty crude. I just ennumerate all the pages I want to scrape, which is a few hundred. I need to get this done, so I might just grit my teeth and bear it like a moron, but it would be so much nicer to automate this. How could this process be implemented with link extraction using scrapy? I've looked at the documentation and made some experiments as I desribe in the question linked above but nothing yet has  worked. This is the brute force code:

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from brute_force.items import BruteForceItem

class DmozSpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "brutus"
    allowed_domains = ["tool.httpcn.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://tool.httpcn.com/Html/Zi/21/PWAZAZAZXVILEPWXV.shtml",
              "http://tool.httpcn.com/Html/Zi/21/PWAZAZCQCQILEPWB.shtml",
              "http://tool.httpcn.com/Html/Zi/21/PWAZAZCQKOILEPWD.shtml",
              "http://tool.httpcn.com/Html/Zi/21/PWAZAZCQUYILEPWF.shtml",
              "http://tool.httpcn.com/Html/Zi/21/PWAZAZCQMEILEKOCQ.shtml",
              "http://tool.httpcn.com/Html/Zi/21/PWAZAZCQRNILEKOKO.shtml",
              "http://tool.httpcn.com/Html/Zi/22/PWCQKOILUYUYKOTBCQ.shtml",
              "http://tool.httpcn.com/Html/Zi/21/PWAZAZAZRNILEPWRN.shtml",
              "http://tool.httpcn.com/Html/Zi/21/PWAZAZCQPWILEPWC.shtml",
              "http://tool.httpcn.com/Html/Zi/21/PWAZAZCQILILEPWE.shtml",
              "http://tool.httpcn.com/Html/Zi/21/PWAZAZCQTBILEKOAZ.shtml",
              "http://tool.httpcn.com/Html/Zi/21/PWAZAZCQXVILEKOPW.shtml",
              "http://tool.httpcn.com/Html/Zi/21/PWAZAZPWAZILEKOIL.shtml",
              "http://tool.httpcn.com/Html/Zi/22/PWCQKOILRNUYKOTBUY.shtml"]

    def parse(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)

        items = []
        item =  BruteForceItem()

        item["the_strokes"] = hxs.xpath('//*[@id="div_a1"]/div[2]').extract()
        item["character"] = hxs.xpath('//*[@id="div_a1"]/div[3]').extract()
        items.append(item)
        return items
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.http import Request
from brute_force.items import BruteForceItem
from urlparse import urljoin

class DmozSpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "brutus"
    allowed_domains = ["tool.httpcn.com"]
    start_urls = ['http://tool.httpcn.com/Zi/BuShou.html']

    def parse(self, response):
        for url in response.css('td a::attr(href)').extract():
            cb = self.parse if '/zi/bushou' in url.lower() else self.parse_item
            yield Request(urljoin(response.url, url), callback=cb)

    def parse_item(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        item =  BruteForceItem()
        item["the_strokes"] = hxs.xpath('//*[@id="div_a1"]/div[2]').extract()
        item["character"] = hxs.xpath('//*[@id="div_a1"]/div[3]').extract()
        return item
```

try this

1.
the spider start with the start_urls.

2.
self.parse. I just find all the a tag in the td tag.
if the url contains '/zi/bushou' then the response should be go to self.parse again because it is what you called 'second layer'.
if not '/zi/bushou' (i think use a more specific regex here is better) like url. i think it is what you want and goes to parse_item function.

3.
self.parse_item. this is the function that you use to get the information from the final page.

Comment: I just tried it but it didn't output anything, in the summation from scrapy it claims there was an error but i can't figure out what it was/is

Comment: it just says 'log_count/ERROR': 1

Comment: i don't know if that consititues a real error, i don't know where scrapy even keeps the log file, though i'll take a look around for it. i just added that import but still it didn't output anything

Comment: dang, masterful performace- bravo. if you have a chance, would you please explain a bit about how you settled upon that solution? or some reference materials i might check out, teach a man to fish and whatnot! :)

Comment: i add a little explaination. and the scarpy document is my main reference. if you have further issues, i'm glad to help.

Comment: mm, thank you very much. could I ask what page of the documentation did you read about that url operation?

Comment: Hi amow, is there any way you might consider helping me with this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28496672/generalize-link-extracting-code-using-scrapy-grab-all-links-on-a-page-of-a-cer